# Convergence of $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{a_n}{1+a_n^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> We have a positive series $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=1}a_n$. is the following series converge or diverge ?$$\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{a_n}{1+a_n^2}$$

$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{a_n}{1+a_n^2}=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{{\frac 1 {a_n}}+a_n}$$

Now it's easy to see that if $a_n$ either converges or diverges, the series will converge.

Comment: The series does not converge for $a_n = 1$. Perhaps something is amiss in the question?

Comment: Does $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converge? If so, edit your question to add the explanation.

Comment: @5xum it doesn't say weather it converge or diverge.

Comment: Then of @user137846 gave you your answer.

Comment: @user137846 nope everything is here.

Comment: @5xum well but it can converge for some $a_n$ isn't it ?

Comment: Sure, take $a_n=0$ and the series will converge.

Comment: Great, thanks. @5xum

Comment: Without any conditions on $a_n$ you can make the terms of your series equal to any positive numbers.  This question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what to say @Gaffney...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\sum a_n<\infty$ then
$$
\sum\frac{a_n}{1+a_n^2}\le \sum a_n<\infty.
$$
Suppose now that $\sum a_n$ diverges. If $a_n$ is bounded, that is, $a_n\le M$ for some $M$, then
$$
\sum\frac{a_n}{1+a_n^2}\ge\frac{1}{1+M^2}\sum a_n=\infty.
$$
If $a_n$ is unbounded anything can happen. For instance, if $a_n=n^p$, $p\ge0$, then $\sum\frac{a_n}{1+a_n^2}$ converges if and only if $p>1$.